# Glyphicon icons load locally but not in live

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a slider made in bootstrap. The problem is the glyphicon icons are loaded properly in the local server, but not loaded in the live server.

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/slide1.jpg'); ?>" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/slide2.jpg'); ?>" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url('img/slide3.jpg'); ?>" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You should provide more information. This can be, problems with the path. The icons/font was not uploaded.

Comment: if you are using visual studio, some fonts are not getting exported... a known issue.

Comment: No, there is no any problem in the path. I googled about it and others were also facing this problem, but I didn't get any correct answer.

Comment: No, I am not using visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have diferent website versions on you localhost and on production. Either you forgot to upload the fonts directory or any other bootstrap component, either you have diferent bootstrap versions for the two enviroments.

Comment: There is no any problem in the bootstrap version. I am using the same version in both development and production versions. But the icons are not loading in the production version.

Answer (score 0):

Manually navigate to all 4 font files on the production server and see what happens...do you get 404 or a download file? On my own server, in FireFox, I get a download prompt for each file except .svg.  The .svg opens directly (but is empty white page, not an error).

Next, relative to the CSS files, where are they?  Unless you've modified the paths manually, relative to your CSS file that's loaded in the browser, your font files should be up one directory, then in the fonts folder (`../fonts/font-file.ext`).  Does your production server have any kind of auto-compiling/minification tools where you are loading the file from a location other than its original source?

Needless to say without paths to the actual offending location, there is no way for me to debug it based on your HTML.